# UITextView new line unexpected behavior

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextview

I have `UITableView` with manually sizing `UITableViewCells`. Every `UITableViewCell` contains `UITextView`. When adding new text the cell grows and on removing shrinks and the tableview goes up if the text will be hidden from the keyboard. Except when adding a new line by tapping the Return key. Then it sometimes works correctly, but after a couple of new lines (the count differs - it can be 2, it can be 16) the cell just stops growing and when the tableview goes up it just leaves space on the bottom. If I then dismiss the keyboard the cell sizes are recalculated correctly and the new lines are there. This issue does not happen with other text. Then the cell grows and the tableview goes up as intended. Any ideas and/ or workarounds would be appreciated.

Edit: After some more testing I figured out this issue can happen if a lot of text is pasted in the text view so it is not just connected to the new line character

The code I am using to update the textviews is:

In the cell:

```
-(void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView {

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO];
        [self.textViewUpdaterDelegate didChangeTextViewForCell:self];
        [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:YES];
    });

}
```

Then in the delegate:

```
- (void)didChangeTextViewForCell:(nonnull SectionQuestionCell *)cell {

        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:cell.center];
        NSInteger index = indexPath.row;
        Question *question = self.questions[index];

        question.hint = cell.dataTextView.text;

        //to update the table view cell height
        [self.tableView beginUpdates];
        [self.tableView endUpdates];

        CGRect cursor = [cell.dataTextView caretRectForPosition:cell.dataTextView.selectedTextRange.start];
        CGRect convertedCursor = [cell.dataTextView convertRect:cursor toView:self.tableView.superview];

        CGFloat allHeight = self.tableView.superview.frame.size.height;
        CGFloat cursorEnd = convertedCursor.origin.y + convertedCursor.size.height;
        CGFloat visibleHeight = allHeight - self.keyboardHeight;
        if (visibleHeight >= cursorEnd && cursorEnd > 0) {
            //it means it is in the visible part
            return;
        }

        CGFloat difference = 0;
        if (cursorEnd >= 0) {
            difference = cursorEnd - visibleHeight;
        } else {
            difference = -convertedCursor.origin.y;
        }

        if (indexPath.row == self.questions.count - 1 && self.tableView.contentSize.height > self.tableView.frame.size.height) {
            [self.tableView beginUpdates];
            [self.tableView endUpdates];
            [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:NO];
        } else if (difference != 0) {
            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
                self.tableViewTopConstraint.constant -= difference;
            }];
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you have scrolling disabled on your text views? Show the code you're using to update the table view when you edit the text views.

Comment: @DonMag Yes, I have scrolling disabled in the text views. I updated the question with the code.

Comment: You've got a bit going on there. I'd suggest... First, put a textView on its own in a view and make sure its height grows / shrinks as expected. Then put a textView in a tableViewCell and have it tell the delegate to call `beginUpdates / endUpdates` and see if that works as expected. If so, then start closely inspecting the rest of your code (that's moving the table up/down to account for the keyboard, I assume) to see what might be causing the issue.